# Convert user crons to system cron

Tags: linux, redhat, cron

I want to centralize a lot of crons to /etc/crontab.
Now every user gots it own crons in /var/spool/cron, which is not maintaineble for me.
I want to do this automated via a script, but the problem is that the cron syntax differs.
In /etc/crontab an user must be stated.
How can I get this task done efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

You might start with something like:

```
while read user; 
    do crontab -l -u $user >> usersTabs;
done < <(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd )
```

It really depends, do you want them to run as the same user they were before?

Answer (score 0):

If my google is correct, the difference in the format is:

```
     * syntax:
     *   user crontab:
     *      minutes hours doms months dows cmd\n
     *   system crontab (/etc/crontab):
     *      minutes hours doms months dows USERNAME cmd\n
```

Assuming you have the output from users crontabs in a folder, you could do something like:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -e perl -pe "s/((\w+\s+){5})(.*)/\1USERNAME \3/;"
```

I don't know if this crontab output makes sense for you, so double check that.
It should be possible to make this script even simpler with better perl or using a different tool like awk or sed, but I can't remember the syntax right now.